# Cakephp $this->layout = 'ajax'

Tags: cakephp, jquery

my css dosnt seem to work when i declare $this->layout = 'ajax' in my controller.

in my view1.ctp, i created a dialog box using jquery. the content will be getting from view2.ctp via jquery.ajax(). i created the html classes, id and all similar to view1.ctp.

the content im receiving is ok. the problem is that the id and classes i declared within view2.ctp is not working. in short, im getting an empty dialog design.

any idea on how to solve this? thank you in advance. cheers!

in my view1.ctp:

```
<div id="thisDialog">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>  

<script>
    jQuery('.test_box').live('click',function(){
        jQuery('#content').empty();
        jQuery.ajax({
            async:false,
            url: '/controller1/view2/'+id //url pointing to my 1controller.php
            success:function(data){
                jQuery('#content').append(data);

            }
        });


        jQuery('#thisDialog').dialog('open');
    });

</script>
```

here is controller1.php

```
function view2($id)
    {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $query = $this->Model->find('all') //somequery here
}
```

here is view2.ctp

```
<div class='box'>
     <div class='title'>
          <h5>Title here</h5>
     </div>
     <div class='contents'>
         <table>
             <tr>
             <td class='head'></td>
              <td class='head'></td>
              </tr> 
              <tr>
               <td class='alt'>Field content1 here</td>
               <td>Fields content2 here</td>
              </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you also add your default.ctp and ajax.ctp?

Answer (score 4):

The AJAX layout is a simple blank file which only contains the HTML (or other content) scrap that you output. It does not contain any stylesheets because the style info should come from the page that you are inserting the content into. Defining your styles for the ID and classes in the calling page will solve your problem.

Comment: i have a layout.ctp where view1.ctp is being called usign $contents_for_layout. i have included all the stylesheet in the <head> tag of layout.ctp. the stylesheet i declared in layout.ctp is applied to view1.ctp. correct me if im wrong, are you trying to explain that i have to redeclare the stylesheet in my view1.ctp for it to be available in my view2.ctp? ^^

Comment: It depends. If the contents of your AJAX call are being inserted into the DOM of layout.ctp then you don't have to redeclare anything. Otherwise, if you are using a litebox or dialog that has its own CSS, you'll have to redeclare. It's easy to find out what's happening if you look at the DOM with Firebug.

Comment: the dialog box is within the layout's DOM and i tried to redeclare my stylesheet inside view1.ctp. still not working. thansl for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ajax' layout can be found in cake/libs/view/layouts/ajax.ctp and it's contents are:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

This essentially only outputs the view, without any surrounding HTML (so no CSS or JS).

Comment: thanks for the reply. so there's no ways of customizing the view using css or js if ill be using $this->layout = 'ajax'?

Comment: you should only use this view if you are sending raw data to an ajax call (JSON objects or HTML snippets). If your page is loaded via ajax in an iframe (some modal plugins do this), then it should use the default layout since the containing page styles do not apply to the iframe contents.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need CSS for 'ajax' layout? Anyway:

1. Layout could be found at /cake/libs/view/layout/ajax.ctp (as said befor it's without common html stuff, just echo to output the data from controller.
2. You can copy this (or default.ctp) file to /app/views/layouts/ajax.ctp so it will be used instead of the one located in cake core files.